# How to divide A4 sheet on parts?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-draw, paragraph

I need to devide A4 sheet on the some parts by 65x50 drawing dotted borders to cut it after printing.

As result I need to get printed a4 with lines of cut.

How to do that and what tool to use?

Comment: 65x50 does not go evenly into 297x210, so you’ll end up with margins. You can get a grid of 4x4 areas on a sheet of A4 paper (for a total of 260x200 mm). You can use any number of tool to make dotted lines – Illustrator, Photoshop, InDesign, Corel Draw, Inkscape, any of the Affinity products, etc. It’s just a matter of drawing the lines and making them dotted. A vector-based app (like Illustrator, Corel Draw or Inkscape) will probably be the easiest.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how to draw dotted line and clone it in photoshop? Is there any ready solution as grid to print?

Answer (score 1):

To draw a dotted line in Photoshop, use the **Pen Tool** to draw a path, then set the **Stroke Options**, using the **Control Bar** across the top of the screen.

[image]

If you know you need a series of specific sized rectangles you can create a dashed stroke rectangle and merely copy it repeatedly...

[image]

If you'd prefer to have guides for paths, you can create a **New Guide Layout** via the menu by choosing `View > New Guide Layout` and entering your specific dimensions there... then use the guide to align paths you draw.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your comment I assume you have got the Adobe CC cloud. I which case it be best to use illustrator for this.

Draw rectangle and set it to right size.

Drag & drop with alt and shift pressed to copy to the right.

Press CMD+D (or CTRL+D in windows) to repeat the copying.

Select line of boxes and copy the same way down.

Select all boxes and press CMD/CTRL + G to group

Centre using the alignment panel

And set stroke to dotted line in stroke panel